# Sentence combining via coordination

Tags: conjunctions, coordination

I know you would use *but* to combine two opposite ideas, and use *and* to combine two similar ideas. And I understand that *similar* would imply that the relationship between the two should not be cause and effect or one that explains the other, so they are two separate thoughts.

The two sentences below are similar, but the second one explains or details the first, and so, I think, it does not lend itself to coordination using *and*.

> Saturn has about twenty moons. Titan is the largest.

In other words, what do you think of combining the previous sentences with and?

> Saturn has about twenty moons, and Titan is the largest.

The example was a run-on sentence from the book Elements of Language, and was fixed by splitting the two ideas. However, I would like to find out whether the approach was the only way or just a matter of preference.

Comment: Your example is an excellent use of the conjunction "and".

Answer (score 1):

*And* is fine to use in this sentence, but there are a wide range of possible conjunctions in English besides *and*, *but*, and *or*.  Many are more specialized to fit a particular circumstance -- for example, in the case where you want to join A to B, where B is *one example* of A, the conjunction "of which" works nicely:

> Saturn has about twenty moons, *of which* Titan is the largest.

So I think that while *and* is usually a perfectly acceptable way to join two sentences, it's not always the *best* way.

[A large (but not comprehensive) list of English conjunctions](http://www.smart-words.org/linking-words/conjunctions.html)

Comment: I wouldn't go along with that. "Which" is clearly anaphoric in your example, and hence the expression "of which Titan is the largest" must be a relative clause. The relative phrase is the preposition phrase "of which" where "which" is the complement of the prep "of" with the noun phrase "about twenty moons" as antecedent. Such relative constructions are very common

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it is problematic to call *of which* a conjunction. I would call *which* here a relative pronoun in the relative clause *of which Titan is the largest*. I was gonna write this last night but got distracted.